# jqGrid Strange behavior with 'loadComplete': vs loadComplete:function()

Tags: events, jqgrid

I have a function that runs in load complete event, however, depending on which loadComplete I use in my grid, one way it works and one way it does not.

For example, I want to modify color of particular div on the the table after load complete. so I have

```
$(grid).jqGrid(
{...options...

    loadComplete: function()
    {
        changeColor();
    }
...remaining grid options/events
)};
```

I can see the code inside the changeColor work, but then coloring reverts back to before code when grid is done.

**BUT** If I have this...

```
$(grid).jqGrid(
{...options...

    'loadComplete': changeColor,

...remaining grid options/events
)};
```

the code changes color and stays there. I also tried gridComplete: function() and got same result as using loadComplete:function().

Based on what I am seeing, it appears to me that the grid continues to load after loadComplete:function() but not after 'loadComplete':.

I also discovered, by accident, that if grid contains both loadComplete:function() and 'loadComplete', the 'loadComplete' fires.

I can work around the issue described above(I don't like to), but if anyone know why this occurs i would appreciate an answer.

Using jqGrid 5.0.2.

Thanks.

Comment: If `changeColor` do finally not what you expect than you should post the code of the function. The main difference between `loadComplete: changeColor` and `loadComplete: function() {changeColor();}` - you don't forward `this` value and the parameters to `changeColor`. The code `loadComplete: function() {changeColor.apply(this, arguments);}` should do this.

Comment: @Oleg I appreciate the info.  For now, I will use the 'loadComplete' which works.  Due to time contraints I do not have time to research further.